# Find maxi,minimum $f(x,y)=x^3+y^3 (\text{where} ~~~ x,y\in \mathbb{R}, x^2+y^2=1)$

Tags: calculus

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: Find maximum and minimum of $f(x,y)$ that
$$f(x,y)=x^3+y^3 (\text{where} ~~~ x,y\in \mathbb{R}, x^2+y^2=1)$$

Comment: Lagrange Multipliers.

Comment: How to look this way without the use of Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: Maybe Am-GM? Or Minkowski inequality?

Answer (score 6):

Find max:

$x^2 + y^2 = 1 \implies x, y\in[-1,1] \implies x^2 \ge x^3,  y^2\ge y^3 \implies 1 = x^2+y^2\ge x^3 + y^3$

Follow that, find min: It is easy to see that $x^3 + y^3$ min $\iff$ $x, y < 0$ and $|x^3 + y^3|$ max

---

Cleaner:
$$x^2 \ge |x|^3,  y^2\ge |y|^3 \implies 1= x^2 + y^2 \ge|x^3|+|y^3| \ge|x^3 +y^3|$$ 
$$\iff x^3+y^3 \in[-1,1]$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use a parametrization of the curve (circle):
$$x=\cos(t), y=\sin(t), t \in [0,2\pi[$$
and minimize 
$$\cos^3(t)+\sin^3(t), t \in [0,2\pi[$$
which can be simplified, to

$$(\cos(t)+\sin(t))(1-\cos(t)\sin(t)), t \in [0,2\pi[$$

as @AHH has shown. You have now to find min and may for a function with on variable

Comment: Ahhh, the use of a parametrization of a covering space to simplify a minimization problem. Such beauty :D

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$ f(x,y)=x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=(x+y)(1-xy)$ such that $ x^2+y^2=1 $